# Copy a spreadsheet file to Google Drive and replace all the formulas with values

Tags: javascript, google-apps-script, google-sheets, google-drive-api

I have a script which copys/clones an Google Spreadsheet and all tabs, which works fine but it I would like it to paste as values.

Here is what i have at the moment

```
function cloneGoogleSheet() {
  var destFolder = DriveApp.getFolderById("your_drive_folder_id"); 
  DriveApp.getFileById("your_drive_source_file_id").makeCopy("particular_file_name", destFolder); 
}
```

Comment: Please add a brief description of your search/research efforts as is suggested in [ask].

Comment: I have looked through stackoverflow for similar questions and youtube to see how to copy a file as values but finding it difficult to locate, which is the reason for the question post

Comment: Do you mean you want to copy the content of Sheets?

Comment: Each tab within the Google sheet to be pasted as a value when a copy is made of the Google Sheet

Answer (score 2, accepted):

### Solution:

The comments provide an explanation of each step:

```
function cloneGoogleSheet() {
  // get the destination folder
  const destFolder = DriveApp.getFolderById("your_drive_folder_id"); 
  // make a copy of a spreadsheet file
  const file = DriveApp.getFileById("your_drive_source_file_id")
                       .makeCopy("particular_file_name", destFolder); 
  // get the spreadsheet file you just created
  const ss = SpreadsheetApp.openById(file.getId());
  // get all the sheets of the spreadsheet file
  const sheets = ss.getSheets();
  // for every sheet copy only the contents
  sheets.forEach(sh=>{
     let rng = sh.getDataRange();
     rng.copyTo(rng, {contentsOnly:true});
     SpreadsheetApp.flush();             
  });
}
```

**Please note:**

If the values are coming from an `importrange` formula then you need to manually allow it before you overwrite the sheet with the values. Because if you don't allow it, then `importrange` does not return anything.

In this case:

- run the version of your script (in your original question)
- go to the newly created spreadsheet and manually allow the `importranges`
- run the following script:

  ```
  function copyValues(){
     const ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActive(); // in case you execute the script 
     bound to the spreadsheet
     //  const ss = SpreadsheetApp.openByUrl("spreadsheet_url") // in case you 
     run it from standalone or other script
     // get all the sheets of the spreadsheet file
     const sheets = ss.getSheets();
     // for every sheet copy only the contents
     sheets.forEach(sh=>{
       let rng = sh.getDataRange();
       rng.copyTo(rng, {contentsOnly:true});
       SpreadsheetApp.flush();             
  });
  }
  ```

If you execute this code from the newly created spreadsheet file, namely you have a script bound to that, then you can use `SpreadsheetApp.getActive()`. If you run the code from a standalone script or a script bound to another spreadsheet, then you need to specify the `url` of the newly created spreadsheet, therefore you can use either `openById` or `openByUrl` as in the example above.

Comment: This had made a copy and not carried over any formulas but the contents is blank

Comment: @Alexasks I can't reproduce your issue. Can you provide more details regarding what you are passing as `your_drive_source_file_id` file? I assume (based on your question) it is a spreadsheet id. The above script, for every sheet, copies the values of the cells and pastes them in the same range. If the contents are black, it means that there was no value in these cells. A cell might have a formula, but if the formula does not return anything, then the value of the cell is blank therefore the script will simply copy the empty value this is why you see blank cells. Can you confirm that?

Comment: @Alexasks Do your spreadsheet includes IMPORTRANGE ?

Comment: @Alexasks  I added `SpreadsheetApp.flush();` in the code in case that issue occurs because of the pending changes. However, Ruben has a valid point. If there are importranges to be allowed then you can only manually do that and then run a script to copy the values.

Comment: @Marios Copies of spreadsheet having MPORTRANGE should manually being clicked on "Allow access" button before the `copyTo(rng, {contensOnly:true})` or similar operations.

Comment: @Rubén yes exactly. I will update my answer to cover this scenario.. thanks :)

Comment: An alternative using the copy as the source of the data to be copied, it might be better to take the values from the original spreadsheet. This might make the code a bit more complex but will not require to do the manual clicking on "allow access".

Comment: @Rubén yeah good idea. Let's see if the OP replies to know what the issue is because right now we don't even know if that is the issue.

Comment: Thank you for your responses :), yes the sheet has formulas and importranges, I will try both examples now and let you know.. thank you again

Comment: Hi both, if it is possible to get passed having to manually allow access for all importranges that would be great

Comment: @Alexasks could you post a separate question regarding that because it needs a whole different approach? In this way readers can benefit from two questions. `importranges` can't be allowed prorammatically. So we need to write a brand new script for that. Feel free to provide the url of the new question here so I can have a look at it and consider accepting this one. Sorry for the incovenience.

Comment: Thank you so much, apologies for this,

New question https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66067520/clone-googlsheet-which-has-formulas-importranges

Comment: @Alexasks [What should I do when someone answers my question?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers)